# Magento 2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: magento2, swatches

When I tried to select the **product color swatch** and **product size** I got this **error** in **production mode**.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at new Function (<anonymous>)
    at Function._.template (eval at require.load (http://217.160.142.147/pub/static/version1522436350/_cache/merged/9f0e77a0e649eade7c26426be1fcf110.min.js:170:216), <anonymous>:64:39)
    at eval (eval at require.load (http://217.160.142.147/pub/static/version1522436350/_cache/merged/9f0e77a0e649eade7c26426be1fcf110.min.js:170:216), <anonymous>:6:73)
    at $.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._UpdatePrice (eval at require.load (http://217.160.142.147/pub/static/version1522436350/_cache/merged/9f0e77a0e649eade7c26426be1fcf110.min.js:170:216), <anonymous>:37:107)
    at $.(anonymous function).(anonymous function).eval [as _UpdatePrice] (eval at require.load (http://217.160.142.147/pub/static/version1522436350/_cache/merged/9f0e77a0e649eade7c26426be1fcf110.min.js:170:216), <anonymous>:28:334)
    at $.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._OnClick (eval at require.load (http://217.160.142.147/pub/static/version1522436350/_cache/merged/9f0e77a0e649eade7c26426be1fcf110.min.js:170:216), <anonymous>:28:156)
    at $.(anonymous function).(anonymous function).eval [as _OnClick] (eval at require.load (http://217.160.142.147/pub/static/version1522436350/_cache/merged/9f0e77a0e649eade7c26426be1fcf110.min.js:170:216), <anonymous>:28:334)
    at HTMLDivElement.eval (eval at require.load (http://217.160.142.147/pub/static/version1522436350/_cache/merged/9f0e77a0e649eade7c26426be1fcf110.min.js:170:216), <anonymous>:24:561)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (eval at require.load (http://217.160.142.147/pub/static/version1522436350/_cache/merged/9f0e77a0e649eade7c26426be1fcf110.min.js:170:216), <anonymous>:339:447)
    at HTMLDivElement.elemData.handle (eval at require.load (http://217.160.142.147/pub/static/version1522436350/_cache/merged/9f0e77a0e649eade7c26426be1fcf110.min.js:170:216), <anonymous>:312:172)
```

Comment: do you use any module with `eval` code. if so contact the module developer

Comment: The problem with the product seem to be when the product has tier price set and what to select the product with color and size... can someone give a hint?

Answer (score 0):

I installed a module named "Apptrian_Minify". The error beginning after the enable this module.
For fix, just disabled this module. Everything alright.